# Gmail Imap - Can't connect when I am in office network

Tags: java, gmail-imap

I have been working at home on Gmail-Imap-Api on the weekend. It was working Properly But when i returned to office and am trying here it throws exception.

```
    Properties props = System.getProperties();
    props.put("mail.store.protocol", "imaps");
    props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");

    try {
        boolean debug = false;
        Authenticator auth = new SMTPAuthenticator(
                "***", "***");

        Session session = Session.getInstance(props, auth);
        session.setDebug(debug);
        Store store = session.getStore("imaps");
        store.connect("imap.gmail.com", "***@gmail.com",
                "****");
    ......
    ......
```

This was working fine at home netwrok.
Now i thought i would add proxy and added these lines of code.

```
    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "****.com");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
```

Still it doesnt work and the exception is.

```
com.google.code.javax.mail.MessagingException: imap.gmail.com;
nested exception is:
java.net.UnknownHostException: imap.gmail.com
at com.google.code.com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:665)
at com.google.code.javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:295)
at com.google.code.javax.mail.Service.connect(Service.java:176)
at openReports.OpenReportsProject.main(OpenReportsProject.java:43)
Caused by: java.net.UnknownHostException: imap.gmail.com
at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(PlainSocketImpl.java:177)
at java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(SocksSocketImpl.java:367)
at java.net.Socket.connect(Socket.java:524)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:545)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(BaseSSLSocketImpl.java:141)
at com.google.code.com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.createSocket(SocketFetcher.java:288)
at com.google.code.com.sun.mail.util.SocketFetcher.getSocket(SocketFetcher.java:231)
at com.google.code.com.sun.mail.iap.Protocol.<init>(Protocol.java:113)
at com.google.code.com.sun.mail.imap.protocol.IMAPProtocol.<init>(IMAPProtocol.java:110)
at com.google.code.com.sun.mail.imap.IMAPStore.protocolConnect(IMAPStore.java:632)
... 3 more
```

Comment: You must be behind a firewall/proxy and the port (which I guess is 993) used by Gmail-Imap needs to be opened in your firewall.

Comment: How to approach to it now? 
I added the proxy settings ryt? will it not serve the purpose here?

Comment: Can you please tell me how to do that? Sorry if its a straight forward question. :)

Comment: I posted the the solution as answer. Please see  if it helps you.

Comment: Try to get it working with an email client like Outlook Express before  coding it in java. It will save you some headaches :)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The proxy settings that you have entered will work only for HTTP connections. IMAP is a different protocol operating on a different port (993 in this case). If you are behind firewall, your firewall needs to allow connection to the external host:port AND the protocol. **You need to request to your Network Administrator for this**. Once the settings are in place you will be able to communicate to Gmail Imap server on default/specified port with specified protocol.